# how to set or know scaling driver in linux kernel

Tags: linux-kernel, cpu-frequency

I am trying to modify the scheduler/governor. For the same I need to know what CPUFreq Driver  or scalling driver am I configured to run.

1.Where can I find what scaling driver am I configured to run?

Also , Since I couldn’t figure out what scaling driver I was running, I tried to look to do the following from adb shell on my android emulator running kernel version 3.4.67 =>

```
cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu2/cpufreq/scaling_driver
```

I found that /sys/devices/system does not exist there.

I also tried to look at sysfs on my android device Nexus 5(Unrooted). It also did not have the above directory in it.

So how do I find out what scaling driver am I running ?